# What am I not understanding about Recursive Sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I've asked this question hours ago and the answers left me a little confused... I hope I don't get stormed for this repost. I'm not sure if my previous question will show up now so I'm reposting it with some clarification as to my confusion.. sorry in case I'm wrong here!

So I have the following equation:

$$c(1)=6$$
$$c(n)=c(n-1)-16$$

-Find the third sequence-

The way I thought about doing it:
$$c(2)=6(2-1)-16 = -10$$
$$c(3)=6(3-1)-16 = -4$$
I know the correct answer is: $$c(3) = -26$$

But I'm little confused.. when you look at the function its
$$c(1)=6$$
$$c(n)=c(n−1)−16$$
So why is it that we don't continue using the formula @_@?:
$$c(2)=6(2−1)−16$$
$$or$$
$$c(3)=6(3−1)−16$$

obviously there is a reason that it's labeled a "sequence".. would like to recognize one without the label tho. Would love some clarification for a noob, thanks!

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing $c(n)$ with multiplication of $c$ by $n$?

Comment: Yeah.. is that wrong?

Comment: Yes.  You can think of $c(\cdot)$ as a function which takes natural numbers as inputs and outputs another number (in this case an integer, but it could be more general).  In the same way that we often write $f(x)$ to denote function $f$ acting on the input $x$ to produce the corresponding output, so too is $c(n)$ a function taking $n$ as input and outputting something else.  The point here is that what it outputs is written not in terms of only $n$ but also in terms of earlier values of the function.

Comment: You can also think of $c$ as a list of numbers.  $c(n)$ refers to the $n$'th entry of the list.  We are told that the first entry of the list is $6$.  We are told that the second entry in the list is sixteen less than the first entry.  We are further told that to continue writing down numbers in the list we subtract sixteen from the previous entry, whatever that happened to be.

Comment: Think $c_n$ instead of $c(n)$.

Comment: I see now.... guys thanks so much. Can someone write this as an answer so that I could label it as such? If you could also incl. how we can identify the difference c(n) to multiplication in an answer would be awesome.

Comment: "Find the third sequence"?? What does "third sequence" mean? What are the first two sequences?

Comment: "third term of..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down to brass tacks...

$c_2 = c_1 - 16= -10$.

$c_3 = c_2 - 16 = -10 -16 = -26$.

If $c(n)$ meant the multiplication of $c$ by $n$ then $c(1)=6$ means that $c=6$ since $c \times 1=c$.  This isn't a recursive sequence, but a constant.  This clearly wasn't what was intended, so we don't read it that way.

I suppose it's worth pointing out that if you thought it meant multiplication your recursion $c(n) = c(n-1)-16$ would mean $cn= cn -c -16$ and cancelling the $cn$'s gives $c=-16$, which contradicts my previous false derivation of $c=6$, so it's all nonsense.